# Can you execute a single line as a target of a python Thread?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have the following code:

```
errorThread = Thread(
    target=tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", b[-1][z:]),
    args=())
errorThread.daemon = True
errorThread.start()
```

I know I could make another function and pass the argument, but out of curiosity can you execute a single line of python code as a target for a Python Thread?

Comment: Why don't you try it? :)

Comment: I did try it, it didn't work, but I didn't know if there was a certain way you'd have to format it. For the time being it's its own one line function.

Comment: Ok. This `errorThread = Thread(target=print,args=("howdy"))` technically works in python3 (no syntax errors or such) which makes sense since it's just another function; the only difference being that it's not written by the user (or at least that's my understanding of it but I could be wrong). Anyway, I'd also go for the lambda expression as @Kevin suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) as your target. That is, after all, what lambdas are for: creating single-expression callables without having to spend a whole line on a function definition.

```
errorThread = Thread(target=lambda: tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", b[-1][z:]))
```

Comment: I was not aware of lambda, so yeah, that is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass those arguments in the `args` keyword argument. Like this:

```
errorThread = Thread(
    target=tkMessageBox.showerror,
    args=("Error", b[-1][z:]))
errorThread.daemon = True
errorThread.start()
```

Comment: Now I feel silly for not even realizing this solution.  Definitely provides for some clean code so I'll be using this, but the other solution actually answers the original question in case another user stumbles upon here decades down the road  (plus I have seen lambda in other SO questions/answers but never used them myself).